# Iterate over two lists Python of different lengths

Tags: python

I'm trying iterate over two lists in python. When I do it  the way below it only prints over the first three items in list `lstTwo`.

My code looks something like this:

```
lstOne = ["pmCat","pmDog","pmMouse"]
lstTwo = ['0', '197', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '4', '0', '197', '0']

for (y,z) in zip(lstOne,lstTwo):
    print(y,z)
```

I tried zip_longest, but it gives you the entire second list but only the first three out of the first list.

I'm trying to have it print something like:

pmCat 0
pmDog 197
pmMouse 0
pmCat 0
pmDog 0
pmMouse 0
pmCat 1
pmDog 0
pmMouse 4
pmCat  0
pmDog 197
pmMouse  0

Comment: You probably should use [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: Inspect the output of `zip(listOne, lstTwo)` and you'll see you're actually trying to iterate over a datastructure that looks like this `[('pmCat', '0'), ('pmDog', '197'), ('pmMouse', '0')]` which should explain why it only prints the first three elements

Comment: I tried zip_longest, but it gives you the entire second list but only the first three out of the first list. 

I'm trying to have it print something like:
<br>
pmCat 0<br>
pmDog 197<br>
pmMouse 0<br>
pmCat 0<br>
pmDog 0
pmMouse 0<br>
pmCat 1<br>
pmDog 0<br>
pmMouse 4<br>
pmCat  0<br>
pmDog 197<br>
pmMouse  0<br>